# Rails ActiveRecord summary statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to translate this simple query to ruby on rails ActiveRecord

`select sum(current*progress) from features;`

i have tried

```
 @feature = Feature.where(project_detail_id: @project_detail.id )
 @current_progress =  @feature.current * @feature.progress
 @total_current_progress =  @feature.sum(@current_progress)
```

but nothing works
i cannot get `@total_current_progress` result

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@total_current_progress = Feature.where(project_detail_id: @project_detail.id).sum("current*progress")
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
@feature = Feature.where(project_detail_id: @project_detail.id )
@current_progress =  @feature.pluck(:current).map(&:to_f).sum * @feature.pluck(:progress).map(&:to_f).sum
@total_current_progress =  @current_progress
```

Comment: your current code logic is `select sum(current)*sum(progress) from features;` but the problem in this case is `select sum(current*progress) from features;` its different mate

Answer (score 0):

```
Feature.sum("current * progress")

(0.7ms)  SELECT SUM(current * progress) FROM "features"
```